# How to extend root partition size of dualboot ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, gparted, disk-management

I dual booted my PC 2 years ago, and I installed a 50gb partition for Ubuntu. But now I use Ubuntu most of the time. And now there is no space remaining in my Ubuntu partition. I have watched several tutorials, read many blogs, but still can't extend my Ubuntu partition size. 
I have tried using GParted in Ubuntu and Disk Management in Windows. But in Gparted, I can't extend ext4 partition size 
[Image of GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoZSI.png)

And in case of Disk Management it only shows delete and help option for the Ubuntu partition. There are no extend option.
[Image of Disk Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMPh7.jpg)

I have a lot of free space in other drives, please someone suggest me the solution

`free -h`:

`total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        2.8G        761M        1.2G        4.1G        3.4G
Swap:          1.9G          0B        1.9G`

`grep -i swap /etc/fstab`:

`# swap was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=6d6b17ee-13d7-49f9-90aa-6a1118c56698 none     swap    sw       0       0`

`sudo blkid | grep -i swap`:

`/dev/sda8: UUID="6d6b17ee-13d7-49f9-90aa-6a1118c56698" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="93bc1965-08"`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105842/discussion-on-question-by-md-shafiqul-islam-how-to-extend-root-partition-size-of).

Comment: No @EricCarvalho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note: Make sure that any data on /dev/sda5, /dev/sda6, and /dev/sda7 (Windows drives D:, E:, and F:) are backed up, as we're going to DELETE them below!**

**Note: Once started, do not stop or abort this process during the APPLY stages!**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **delete** partition /dev/sda5
- **delete** partition /dev/sda6
- **delete** partition /dev/sda7
- this should leave approx 450G of unallocated space to the left of /dev/sda8
- click the Apply icon to save what you've done so far
- **did you remember to `swapoff` on /dev/sda8?**
- **move** partition /dev/sda8 all the way left
- **move** partition /dev/sda9 all the way left
- **resize** the right side of partition /dev/sda9 all the way right
- click the Apply icon again
- when the /dev/sda8 and /dev/sda9 move/resizes are complete, reboot the computer

Comment: Currently I don't have any pendrive as I lost one recently, 
Should I go through the procedures skipping,"boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB"? Or I need to wait till I get a new pendrive?

Comment: You'll need to build a new Ubuntu Live USB flash drive, or burn a Ubuntu Live DVD. Can't do anything without.

Comment: Your solution worked, Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Md.ShafiqulIslam Great news! Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0):

When you reformat the sda7 partition, you will probably want to add a partition for your /home to make storing your personal files easier, as I believe that makes mounting them easier when you update or change the operating system.

Comment: Weak answer. Should be a comment.

Comment: You make a good point about using other partitions as mountable filespace.  No need to worry about contiguous partitions at all for this approach, and the original question indicates the root is already at 50G, larger than most recommendations.

Comment: @ubfan1 OP doesn't indicate that / is 50G (assumes a separate /home), they say the Ubuntu partition is at 50G... and all used up...